# Iptables connecting between two subnets

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I have a Linux machine (which I want to use as a gateway) and two other machines A and B. Gateway machine has eth0, eth1, and eth2. 
eth1 connects to machine A and eth2 connects to machine B. I want to be able to ping from A to B and the other way around.
I tried to do it using `iptables`, and added FOWARDING rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

But I am getting "host is unreachable" when trying to ping.

When I run

```
iptables -L -n -V
```

I can see that the forwarding rules got 0 packets and 0 bytes.
Now I know I might missing a few more things, but it looks like the FORWARDING chain is never reached. When according to documentation if it’s not the destination it will go to FORWARDING chain.

**EDIT 1:**
i cleaned the iptables and started from scratch using the following commnads

```
    iptables -A FORWARD  -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD  -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -j DNAT --to-destination y.y.y.y
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth2 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -d y.y.y.y -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -d x.x.x.x -j SNAT --to-source y.y.y.y
```

Still getting "network is unreachable"

Comment: Read about masquerading and routing.

Comment: I know i need to use nat rules but even without it i should see packets getting to the FORWARD chain

Answer (score 3):

Your misconception is that you seem to think that `iptables` does the forwarding.

The rules you used in the first example merely allow forwarding. Forwarding is already allowed by default, so these rules make sense only as exceptions to a general deny rule that comes later.

You just have to enable packet forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Of course, your gateway should be the default gateway for both `A` and `B`, or at least it must be the gateway to reach each other. So if it doesn't work with forwarding enabled, you should include the routing tables on all three machines.